# Is it possible to control SoundCloud applications from side-apps using HTTP requests?

Tags: soundcloud

I need to cast media from SoundCloud to Chromecast from my custom application but have not found any info about it in the SoundCloud API documentation. So I've come to this solution:

I have got two applications: Custom App, which I am currently working on, and the SoundCloud App (for instance SoundCloud APK for Android) which is intended to do Chromecasting as a response to requests from my side app. So my question is: is it possible to control SoundCloud apps using HTTP requests? If so could you provide me any documentation of this API?

Answer (score 0):

No: it is not possible to control SoundCloud's Android application from another application using HTTP requests. This is not a feature.